# Applying a min function with Poisson random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For context, here is the question:

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ form a random sample from a Poisson distribution. The poisson distribution has a mean of 1. Let $Y=\min(X_1,X_2)$. P(Y=1)=...

I have the solution, but I just don't understand 1 key aspect of it aspects of it.

Here goes:

The solution starts with $P(Y=1)=\bigg(P(X_1=1)\cap (X_2 \geq 1)+P(X_2=1)\cap (X_1\geq2)\bigg)$

The lefthand side makes enough sense to me, that is, it is a situation in which $X_1$ is the least value, that is =1, and $X_2$ is anything that is at least 1. The righthand side doesn't make very much sense at all to me. In this case, when $X_2=1$, why are we suddenly interested in this, combined with the probability that $X_1\geq2$  and not 1?

Comment: Because otherwise, both events are not disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative Solution

I'm not a fan of the solution you're provided, so I'll approach this in a slightly different way.

So we have this random variable $Y$, which is the smallest of $X_1$ and $X_2$. We want the probability that $Y = 1$. This could occur in one of three ways, keeping in mind that $Y$ is the smallest of $X_1, X_2$:

1. $X_1 = 1$ and $X_2 > 1$ - or equivalently - $X_1 = 1$ and $X_2 \geq 2$
2. $X_2 = 1$ and $X_1 > 1$ - or equivalently - $X_1 \geq 2$ and $X_2 = 1$
3. $X_1 = X_2 = 1$

The third situation above is the easiest one: by independence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1 \cap X_2 = 1) &= \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_2 = 1) \\
&= \dfrac{e^{-1}1^1}{1!} \cdot \dfrac{e^{-1}1^1}{1!} \\
&= e^{-2}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

For both of the first and second situations, let $X$ be a random variable which is Poisson distributed with mean $1$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X \geq 2) &= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X < 2) \\
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq 1) \\
&= 1 - \sum_{x = 0}^{1}\mathbb{P}(X = x) \\
&= 1 - \left(\dfrac{e^{-1}1^0}{0!} + \dfrac{e^{-1}1^1}{1!} \right) \\
&= 1 - 2e^{-1}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Because $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and Poisson-distributed with mean $1$, it follows that for both cases 1 and 2, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1 \cap X_2 \geq 2) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_2 \geq 2) 
 = \dfrac{e^{-1}1^1}{1!}\cdot (1 - 2e^{-1}) = e^{-1}(1 - 2e^{-1})$$
thus the desired probability is
$$\begin{align}
\underbrace{e^{-1}(1 - 2e^{-1})}_{\text{case 1}} + \underbrace{e^{-1}(1 - 2e^{-1})}_{\text{case 2}} + \underbrace{e^{-2}}_{\text{case 3}} &= 2e^{-1}(1-2e^{-1}) + e^{-2} \\
&= \dfrac{2(1-2e^{-1})}{e} + \dfrac{1}{e^{2}} \\ 
&= \dfrac{2e(1-2e^{-1})}{e^2} + \dfrac{1}{e^{2}} \\
&= \dfrac{2e(1-2e^{-1}) + 1}{e^2} \\
&= \dfrac{2e(1-2e^{-1}) + 1}{e^2} \\
&= \dfrac{2e - 4 + 1}{e^2} \\
&= \dfrac{2e - 3}{e^2}
\end{align}$$

---

## Explanation of the Provided Solution

The solution you were provided compresses cases (1) and (3) above into one single case, and case (2) as a second case.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid double counting $P(X_1=1 \cap X_2=1)$.

You could write

$$P(Y=1)=P(X_1=1\cap X_2 = 1)+P(X_1=1\cap X_2 \gt 1)+P(X_2=1\cap X_1\gt1)$$

and then use $P(X_1=1\cap X_2 = 1)+P(X_1=1\cap X_2 \gt 1) = P(X_1=1\cap X_2 \geq 1)$, while for a distribution on integers you have  $P(X_2=1\cap X_1\gt1)= +P(X_2=1\cap X_1\geq2)$, so getting your

$$P(Y=1)=P(X_1=1\cap X_2 \geq 1)+P(X_2=1\cap X_1\geq 2)$$